# Multi line format string support in c#/visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to have multiline string support (not verbatim string literals as that honours carriage returns, etc) and without letting the UI add '+' to the end of every line (which I presume means the string table being needlessly added to).

In other words to separate a long line of formatting across multiple lines.

If I press return on the below code the editor is automatically turning this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{a} : {b} : {c}");
```

In to this:

```
        System.Console.WriteLine($"" +
            $"{a} : " +
            $"{b} : " +
            $"{c}");
```

I was hoping to do something like this, or similar

```
        System.Console.WriteLine($"{a} : " _ 
            "{b} : " _
            "{c}");
```

Thanks. Bonus points if it works in Vb.Net too ;-)

Comment: Why you want to do that?

Comment: _"which I presume means the string table being needlessly added to"_ - nope, see duplicate: _"the C# compiler merges literals concatenated with +"_. [From MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings): _"These parts [concatenated by the `+` operator] are concatenated into a single string at compile time. There is no run-time performance cost regardless of the number of strings involved"_.

Comment: That's great, I never knew that, I've been telling people for years to avoid concatenation :)

But it seems the editor for C# is better than vb.net because when you press return it auto adds the closing string and $, but in vb.net you just get a mess.

Comment: I think that's ReSharper who's doing that, isn't it?

Comment: Add ```Environment.NewLine```to the end of each line..